# Unit testing logs using streams working just for the first test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, stream, mockito

I have a JUnit test class, which uses Mockito, in which I need to test if something is being logged correctly. It basically looks something like:

```
public class MyTest {

    private final PrintStream outDefault = System.out;
    private final PrintStream errDefault = System.err;

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));  
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.setOut(outDefault);
        System.setErr(errDefault);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1_Condition_Expected() {
        assertTrue(errContent.toString().toLowerCase().contains("..."));
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void TestN_Condition_Expected() {
        assertTrue(errContent.toString().toLowerCase().contains("..."));
    }
}
```

I have also tried to do a flush and close of the streams in the @After, but it does not seem to work neither:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    try {
        outContent.flush();
        errContent.flush();
        outContent.close();
        errContent.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.setOut(outDefault);
    System.setErr(errDefault);
}
```

When I run the whole class, the first tests passes but the rest don't. If I run the tests one by one then all of them pass.

I have debugged the code and everything seems to work properly, but for tests other than the first one the streams are not getting the logs, so obviously they fail.

Comment: Have you tried flushing after every test?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's not working anyway...

Comment: Which version of JUnit?

Comment: Could you please post the failure message.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can use [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) instead of handling the output stream stuff by yourself.

Comment: @NickDeFazio I'm using version 4.12.

Comment: @StefanBirkner the error is a java.lang.AssertionError. I will check if it is possible to add those System Rules to the project, for me they look a good option, but it's not my decision.

Comment: Are you trying to test a class's logging output by reading what it prints to standard out/err?

Comment: @cantido in the beginning I just wanted to hide some stack traces that were shown each time I did a deploy and run the tests, but then I tried to use that also to test the logging output... but probably there are better ways to do that, aren't them?

Comment: What I'm thinking is that you could mock out the object you're using for logging, and then verify what you're passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ByteArrayOutputStreams you're flushing:

```
outContent.flush();
errContent.flush();
```

...aren't the PrintStreams you're setting:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
```

...and that PrintStream [owns a BufferedWriter](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/PrintStream.java.html#61) and [can be set to auto-flush, but doesn't do so by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html):

> Optionally, a `PrintStream` can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the `flush` method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte (`'\n'`) is written.

My guess is that it's the PrintStream that needs to be flushed before each assertion against `toString()`, not the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

The PrintStream is not flushed when you call `errorContent.toString()` because `@After` is called after your test and it flushes only `errorContent`. You have to flush the PrintStream around `errorContent` before calling `toString()`. The best way is to use [`PrintStream` with `autoFlush` enabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-).

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent, true));  
}
```